# Absolute line numbers on the current and relative line numbers on all other lines?

Tags: line-numbers

I know [this plugin](https://github.com/Fanael/relative-line-numbers) for relative numbers, which works fine (with the option `(global-relative-line-numbers-mode)`. I also know this elisp code, which gives me perfectly working absolute numbers:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook (lambda () (linum-mode 1)))
```

However, i don't know how i can have absolute line numbers on the current and relative line numbers on all other lines (both on the left margin like displayed in the picture below).

[image: this picture of my vim] This picute of my vim shows what i want. Therefore, i don't search for line numbers in the mode line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `relative-line-numbers-mode`, you can customize the formatting to get what you want:

```el
(defun relative-abs-line-numbers-format (offset)
  "The default formatting function.
Return the absolute value of OFFSET, converted to string."
  (if (= 0 offset)
      (number-to-string (line-number-at-pos))
    (number-to-string (abs offset))))

(setq relative-line-numbers-format 'relative-abs-line-numbers-format)
```

This format will then apply to any buffers in `relative-line-number-mode`.

Comment: When i put that into my emacs init file and restart, nothing happens. Neither absolute, nor relative line numbers are visible.

Comment: woops. This assumes you're using `relative-line-numbers mode` already. I'll update